# React-Select not showing options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to implement react-select in my form, but the options are not showing up. If I inspect the select component the options prop is filled, but the options aren't being displayed.

I've tried both an array of strings and an array of objects. Neither displays the info in the dropdown, even though both show up in the options props.

```js
const systems = [
"SystemName/12345/1",
"SytemName1/7890/2",
"SystemName2/65432/3"
]
```

I've also tried:

```js
const systems = 
[{systemName: 'SystemName1", altId:12345, systemId: 1},
{systemName: 'SystemName2", altId:7890, systemId: 2},
{systemName: 'SystemName3", altId:65432, systemId: 3}]

 <form className="page-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Label label="Water System" htmlFor="systemId" required />
                            <Select
                                options={systems}
                                isSearchable={true}
                                name="systemId"
                                value="systemId"
                                placeholder="Select System"
                            />
....
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post what the value of systems is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your options are of the right type -
example from the [docs](https://react-select.com/home)

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

Must be of type `Array<{value:string,label:string}>`

Comment: Thanks - I just thought it was looking for an object, I didn't realize the items in the object had to have specific keys

Comment: labelKey and valueKey can be change you need to pass it as props to select component.

Comment: @ANILPATEL Can you tell tell how to do that? Please

Comment: @AgentK I have written an elaborate answer, I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In react-select v1

```
<Select
   labelKey=labelKey
   valueKey=valueKey
/>
```

In react-select v2 onwards

```
<Select
   getOptionLabel={options => options[labelKey]}
   getOptionValue={options => options[valueKey]}
/>
```

Ex:

```
/* React-Select v2 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

/* Here name is the labelKey and id is the valueKey */

const options = [
  { id: 'value1', name: 'label1'},
  { id: 'value2', name: 'label2'},
  { id: 'value3', name: 'label3'},
]

export default class ReactSingleSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    //suppose you want name as label and id as value
    return (
      <Select
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(options) => options['name']}
        getOptionValue={(options) => options['id']}
      />
    );
  }
}
```